# iPhone is not calling given number, I wonder why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this code snippet,

```
NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber];
    NSLog(@"%@", number);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]];
```

NSLog output is,

```
2011-11-21 15:32:49.621 Tittle-Tattle[1743:707] tel://0413 883 245
2011-11-21 15:32:56.914 Tittle-Tattle[1743:707] tel://0413 873 245
```

Everything seems okay, However my application isn't switching to Phone app and start calling this number. Any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces from the phone number before dialing?

Comment: @sosborn Thank you that worked, put it in answer I will accept and up vote it! thanks cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url string must be devoid of any empty spaces. Using your example the code would read:

```
NSString *number = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber] stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]];
```